# Table bloat on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, soft-delete

I have a small (~200GB) data warehouse running on Postgres 9.5.15 on AWS RDS instance.

For robustness, I'm inserting new data into analytical schema (result of ELT) as follows:

1. insert new slice
2. remove the old slice using delete command
3. vacuum

I know Postgres soft deletes tuples when you execute delete or update commands. This is not a concern giving the table sizes. The problem is that the dead tuples are not removed with explicit vacuum on (3) or regular autovacuum. So, if the pipeline is executed many times, I end up with HUGE table bloat that affects table performance a lot, not mentioning extra storage wasted.

Moreover, when I started investigating I found out that even system tables have this issue:

```
schemaname | relname | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | ratio%
pg_catalog | pg_attribute | 46081 | 8339587 | 18097
pg_catalog | pg_depend | 27375 | 2490507 | 9097
pg_catalog | pg_statistic20094 | 1208474 | 6013
```

That might make general performance of the instance worse in ways I can't even imagine. When I try to do `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE pg_catalog.pg_attribute` it gives me this:

```
"pg_attribute": found 0 removable, 8387117 nonremovable row versions in 152494 pages
```

I have read the articles like "3 reasons of table bloat" but neither does not apply (I'm not doing replication, I don't have hanging transactions, etc.). I can use something like `pg_repack` to get rid of the bloat at some schedule but I'd like to understand the reason why it happens. Also I don't want to repack system tables for sure.

My only hypothesis is that vacuum requires all the dead tuples to fit in memory that is limited to `maintenance_work_mem` setting (127MB for our instance) and we need to increase that but I need a side opinion first.

Comment: Regular DML statements won't affect `pg_attribute` or `pg_depend`. Are you creating and dropping (temp) tables very often? That's typically one of the reasons the system catalogs get bloated. And if `vacuum full` doesn't remove anything, this means you have at least one transaction open that used the tables were the attributes belonged to.

Comment: I do as a part of ELT pipelines, like one table insert requires 3 staging tables before the main insert, and it's done every 3 hours. As for transactions I am checking `pg_stat_activity`, no pointers to these tables.

Comment: ""pg_attribute": found 0 removable, 8387117 nonremovable row versions in 152494 pages"  nonremovable includes both live, and recently dead.  What if you just do a `select count(*) from pg_attribute`?

Comment: Did your verbose vacuums yield lines like "DETAIL:  900000 dead row versions cannot be removed yet."

Comment: You can increase `maintenance_work_mem` temporarily for one command, then revert to your default value, see `SET LOCAL`, not sure if that helps though.

Comment: `pg_stat_activity`won't contain "pointers" to those table - but it would show uncommitted transactions (connections that are "idle in transaction"). Are you constantly dropping and re-creating the staging tables? If yes why?

Comment: @jjanes it gives me 45978, very close to the count of live tuples in the example above

Comment: @jjanes it just gave me what I specified above: `... 8387117 nonremovable row versions`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name by "pointers" I mean the table's name in the query text so that it's clear that the query I see in the activity view touches the table. Also I have tried some queries based on `pg_locks` to identify possible locks and deadlocks on any tables and they returned nothing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as for staging tables, as I said this is a DWH environment so there is a complex business logic for data transformation. Instead of writing a 1000 line query with like 15 WITH statements/subqueries I have split that into smaller chunks that would be responsible for individual layers of the logic and then joined and the result is inserted into the target table that fully describes a business entity (like customer or contract).

Comment: Even back in 9.5, I always get a DETAIL line reporting "nnn dead row versions cannot be removed yet"

Comment: "so that it's clear that the query I see in the activity view touches the table" An open snapshot will prevent tuples from being vacuumed away, even if the transaction has never touched that particular table.

Comment: I understand the concept of staging tables. But you still haven't answered the question if you are constantly dropping and creating them or if you create them only once (or if you have connections that are "idle in transactio").

Comment: @a_hourse_with_no_name yeah I'm dropping and recreating them, or using temp tables. Just not to clutter the namespace. Would it make more sense to truncate after every execution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and I don't have connections that are "idle in transaction". Either idle or active.

Comment: @AlexYes Do you have any update on this? I think I am facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisSekas I came up with repacking the tables on schedule at the end - added an answer here

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own functions to repack the data and running them on schedule:

```
-- repack an individual table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.repack_table(text)
RETURNS text
AS $$
DECLARE SQL text;
BEGIN

    SELECT
     'CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 (LIKE '||$1||');'||chr(10)||
     'INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM '||$1||';'||chr(10)||
     'TRUNCATE TABLE '||$1||';'||chr(10)||
     'INSERT INTO '||$1||' SELECT * FROM t1;'||chr(10)||
     'DROP TABLE t1;'||chr(10)||
     'ANALYZE '||$1||';'
    INTO SQL;
    EXECUTE SQL;
    RETURN $1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- repack all tables in certain schema (with an optional threshold for N of dead tuples)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.repack_schema(text,int default 5000)
RETURNS table (table_name text)
AS $$
DECLARE SQL text;
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY (
    with
     schema as (select $1)
    select admin.repack_table(t.table_schema||'.'||t.table_name)
    from information_schema.tables t
    where t.table_schema=(select * from schema)
    and t.table_name in (
        select relname
        from pg_stat_all_tables
        where schemaname=(select * from schema)
        and n_dead_tup>$2
        and n_live_tup<1000000 -- avoid repacking too large tables
    )
);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bloat Score Query

The following SQL query will examine each table in the public schema and identify dead rows (tuples) that are wasting disk space.

```
SELECT schemaname || '.' || relname as tblnam,
    n_dead_tup,
    (n_dead_tup::float / n_live_tup::float) * 100 as pfrag
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'public' and n_dead_tup > 0 and n_live_tup > 0 order by pfrag desc;
```

**If this query returns a high percentage ( pfrag ) of dead tuples, the VACUUM command may be used to reclaim space.**

**7 Considered to be high**

### From `wiki.postgres.org`

```
SELECT
  current_database(), schemaname, tablename, /*reltuples::bigint, relpages::bigint, otta,*/
  ROUND((CASE WHEN otta=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE sml.relpages::float/otta END)::numeric,1) AS tbloat,
  CASE WHEN relpages < otta THEN 0 ELSE bs*(sml.relpages-otta)::BIGINT END AS wastedbytes,
  iname, /*ituples::bigint, ipages::bigint, iotta,*/
  ROUND((CASE WHEN iotta=0 OR ipages=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE ipages::float/iotta END)::numeric,1) AS ibloat,
  CASE WHEN ipages < iotta THEN 0 ELSE bs*(ipages-iotta) END AS wastedibytes
FROM (
  SELECT
    schemaname, tablename, cc.reltuples, cc.relpages, bs,
    CEIL((cc.reltuples*((datahdr+ma-
      (CASE WHEN datahdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE datahdr%ma END))+nullhdr2+4))/(bs-20::float)) AS otta,
    COALESCE(c2.relname,'?') AS iname, COALESCE(c2.reltuples,0) AS ituples, COALESCE(c2.relpages,0) AS ipages,
    COALESCE(CEIL((c2.reltuples*(datahdr-12))/(bs-20::float)),0) AS iotta -- very rough approximation, assumes all cols
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ma,bs,schemaname,tablename,
      (datawidth+(hdr+ma-(case when hdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE hdr%ma END)))::numeric AS datahdr,
      (maxfracsum*(nullhdr+ma-(case when nullhdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE nullhdr%ma END))) AS nullhdr2
    FROM (
      SELECT
        schemaname, tablename, hdr, ma, bs,
        SUM((1-null_frac)*avg_width) AS datawidth,
        MAX(null_frac) AS maxfracsum,
        hdr+(
          SELECT 1+count(*)/8
          FROM pg_stats s2
          WHERE null_frac<>0 AND s2.schemaname = s.schemaname AND s2.tablename = s.tablename
        ) AS nullhdr
      FROM pg_stats s, (
        SELECT
          (SELECT current_setting('block_size')::numeric) AS bs,
          CASE WHEN substring(v,12,3) IN ('8.0','8.1','8.2') THEN 27 ELSE 23 END AS hdr,
          CASE WHEN v ~ 'mingw32' THEN 8 ELSE 4 END AS ma
        FROM (SELECT version() AS v) AS foo
      ) AS constants
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
    ) AS foo
  ) AS rs
  JOIN pg_class cc ON cc.relname = rs.tablename
  JOIN pg_namespace nn ON cc.relnamespace = nn.oid AND nn.nspname = rs.schemaname AND nn.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  LEFT JOIN pg_index i ON indrelid = cc.oid
  LEFT JOIN pg_class c2 ON c2.oid = i.indexrelid
) AS sml
ORDER BY wastedbytes DESC
```

## Human readable wasted disk space

```
WITH constants AS (
  SELECT current_setting('block_size')::numeric AS bs, 23 AS hdr, 4 AS ma
), bloat_info AS (
  SELECT
    ma,bs,schemaname,tablename,
    (datawidth+(hdr+ma-(case when hdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE hdr%ma END)))::numeric AS datahdr,
    (maxfracsum*(nullhdr+ma-(case when nullhdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE nullhdr%ma END))) AS nullhdr2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      schemaname, tablename, hdr, ma, bs,
      SUM((1-null_frac)*avg_width) AS datawidth,
      MAX(null_frac) AS maxfracsum,
      hdr+(
        SELECT 1+count(*)/8
        FROM pg_stats s2
        WHERE null_frac<>0 AND s2.schemaname = s.schemaname AND s2.tablename = s.tablename
      ) AS nullhdr
    FROM pg_stats s, constants
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
  ) AS foo
), table_bloat AS (
  SELECT
    schemaname, tablename, cc.relpages, bs,
    CEIL((cc.reltuples*((datahdr+ma-
      (CASE WHEN datahdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE datahdr%ma END))+nullhdr2+4))/(bs-20::float)) AS otta
  FROM bloat_info
  JOIN pg_class cc ON cc.relname = bloat_info.tablename
  JOIN pg_namespace nn ON cc.relnamespace = nn.oid AND nn.nspname = bloat_info.schemaname AND nn.nspname <> 'information_schema'
), index_bloat AS (
  SELECT
    schemaname, tablename, bs,
    COALESCE(c2.relname,'?') AS iname, COALESCE(c2.reltuples,0) AS ituples, COALESCE(c2.relpages,0) AS ipages,
    COALESCE(CEIL((c2.reltuples*(datahdr-12))/(bs-20::float)),0) AS iotta -- very rough approximation, assumes all cols
  FROM bloat_info
  JOIN pg_class cc ON cc.relname = bloat_info.tablename
  JOIN pg_namespace nn ON cc.relnamespace = nn.oid AND nn.nspname = bloat_info.schemaname AND nn.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  JOIN pg_index i ON indrelid = cc.oid
  JOIN pg_class c2 ON c2.oid = i.indexrelid
)
SELECT
  type, schemaname, object_name, bloat, pg_size_pretty(raw_waste) as waste
FROM
(SELECT
  'table' as type,
  schemaname,
  tablename as object_name,
  ROUND(CASE WHEN otta=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE table_bloat.relpages/otta::numeric END,1) AS bloat,
  CASE WHEN relpages < otta THEN '0' ELSE (bs*(table_bloat.relpages-otta)::bigint)::bigint END AS raw_waste
FROM
  table_bloat
    UNION
SELECT
  'index' as type,
  schemaname,
  tablename || '::' || iname as object_name,
  ROUND(CASE WHEN iotta=0 OR ipages=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE ipages/iotta::numeric END,1) AS bloat,
  CASE WHEN ipages < iotta THEN '0' ELSE (bs*(ipages-iotta))::bigint END AS raw_waste
FROM
  index_bloat) bloat_summary
ORDER BY raw_waste DESC, bloat DESC
```